# Wordpress - customizer setting overwrites previous setting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

First time I'm working with wordpress and ran in some struggles while trying to add new options in the Customizer panel.

I managed to get one setting in it, but my second setting will overwrite the first and results to showing only one option in the customizer panel.

I don't understand and see what I'm doing wrong here and couldn't find any answers to it on the internet, so figured maybe somebody here could help me out. :)

This is my code currently:

```
    <?php
    add_action( 'customize_register', 'twentyseventeenchild_register_theme_customizer' );
    /*
    * Register Our Customizer Stuff Here
    */
    function twentyseventeenchild_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {
        // Create custom panel.
        $wp_customize->add_panel( 'child_custom_settings', array(
            'priority'       => 500,
            'theme_supports' => '',
            'title'          => __( 'Custom settings', 'twentyseventeen-child' ),
            'description'    => __( 'Set editable text for certain content.', 'twentyseventeen-child' ),
        ) );

        // Add section.
        $wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_header_settings' , array(
            'title'    => __('Header', 'twentyseventeen-child'),
            'panel'    => 'child_custom_settings',
            'priority' => 10
        ) );

        //  =============================
        //  = Header title              =
        //  =============================
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_options[title]', array(
            'default'           => __( '', 'twentyseventeen-child' ),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text'
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'custom_header_settings',
                array(
                        'label'    => __( 'Header title', 'twentyseventeen-child' ),
                        'section'  => 'custom_header_settings',
                        'settings' => 'header_options[title]',
                        'type'     => 'text'
                )
            )
        );

        //  =============================
        //  = Header text               =
        //  =============================
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_options[text]', array(
            'default'           => __( '', 'twentyseventeen-child' ),
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'custom_header_settings',
                array(
                        'label'    => __( 'Header text', 'twentyseventeen-child' ),
                        'section'  => 'custom_header_settings',
                        'settings' => 'header_options[text]',
                        'type'     => 'text'
                )
            )
        );

        // Sanitize text
        function sanitize_text( $text ) {
                return sanitize_text_field( $text );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each new setting, it must have a unique **ID**, you have used **custom_header_settings** for both.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control